# Netlify lambda function timing out after 10 seconds

Tags: netlify

I am having trouble returning data from my Netlify serverless function in my production environment. It currently is timing out after 10 seconds, responding with a status code of 502 and the following error message:

```js
{
  "errorMessage": "2019-... 5f... Task timed out after 10.01 seconds"
}
```

However, in my development environment, the Netlify serverless function works perfectly, responding with the data from my database.

I have confirmed that the environment variables on my Netlify site and in my `.env` file are the same. How would I go about debugging this problem and solving the issue?

---

> **Netlify serverless function**

```js
const { connectDatabase, ProjectSchema } = require('../database')

const createHeaders = origin => {
    // This is a comma-separated list of allowed origins, including my local 
    // environment and production website
    const allowedOrigins = process.env.ALLOWED_ORIGINS
        ? process.env.ALLOWED_ORIGINS.split(',')
        : []

    return {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers':
            'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': allowedOrigins.includes(origin)
            ? origin
            : ''
    }
}

/**
 * This function queries for all `Project` instances in the database and
 * returns it in the response body.
 */
const getProjects = async origin => {
    try {
        const projects = await ProjectSchema.find()

        return {
            headers: createHeaders(origin),
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify({ projects })
        }
    } catch (err) {
        return {
            headers: createHeaders(origin),
            statusCode: 400,
            body: JSON.stringify({ error: err })
        }
    }
}

/**
 * This function is the serverless lambda for `/.netlify/functions/get-projects`.
 */
exports.handler = async event => {
    try {
        await connectDatabase()
        const response = await getProjects(event.headers.origin)
        return response
    } catch (err) {
        return err
    }
}
```

> **Database functions**

```js
require('dotenv').config()
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const { Schema } = mongoose

/**
 * This function establishes a connection to the MongoDB Atlas database.
 */
exports.connectDatabase = async () => {
    await mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    })
}

exports.ProjectSchema = mongoose.model(
    'project',
    new Schema({
        title: {
            type: String,
            required: [true, 'Title field is required']
        },
        description: {
            type: String,
            required: [true, 'Description field is required']
        }
    })
)
```

> **Fetch request from client**

```js
const App = () => {
    const [projects, setProjects] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(API.GET_PROJECTS, {
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(({ projects }) => setProjects(projects))
    }, [])

    return (...)
}
```

> **netlify.toml**

```
[build]
  functions = "functions"
```

> **package.json**

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npm run build:client & npm run build:server",
    "build:client": "webpack --config webpack.client.js",
    "build:server": "netlify-lambda build src/server/functions -c webpack.server.js",
    "start": "netlify-lambda serve src/server/functions",
    "start:dev": "npm run build:client -- --watch"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is probably a bit late to be useful, but netlify functions have a 10 second execution limit: https://docs.netlify.com/functions/overview/#default-deployment-options

They specify that if you need a longer execution time you can speak to their sales team about your use-case and they may be able to adjust it.

What is the execution time when you're running in your development environment?

Comment: its way faster than 10sec

Answer (score 3):

I also had this timeout problem with Mongoose and Netlify Lambda Functions. The problem was that Mongoose keeps the database connection open, which caused the Lambda Function not to finish. My solution was to close the connection at the end of a request with `mongoose.disconnect()`.

```js
await mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
});

// ... do some db stuff

// make sure you close the connection when you are done
mongoose.disconnect();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else has the same issue as I did, the reason I got the time out in production and not locally was because I was using MongoAtlas. In order for netlify functions to access MongoAltas you will have to set the network access for mongo to everyone within mongo atlas...unfortunately. If anyone finds out that I'm incorrect please share but it makes sense because netlify functions are serverless so we can't exactly get an IP address..for security reasons if your infrastructure is very sensitive than I would not recommend using netlify to access your mongo atlas